# Bounding the norm of the difference of matrix inverses

Tags: matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-norms

A seemingly simple question (but not a HW problem). Let $||\cdot||$ be the operator norm and $||\cdot||_F$ be the Frobenius norm. Say that $A, B\in R^{n\times n}$ are symmetric positive definite. Is it possible to find an upper bound for $||A^{-1}-B^{-1}||_F$ as a function of $||A-B||$ and, additionally, $||A||$ or $||A^{-1}||$?

Comment: One lower bound that you might find interesting is
$$
\|A^{-1} - B^{-1}\| \geq \frac{\|A - B\|}{\|A\|\cdot \|B\|}
$$

Comment: Because $A (A^{-1} - B^{-1}) B = B-A$.